# Adding speedbar support for a language major mode?

Tags: speedbar, golang

It appears to me that go-mode and speedbar are not working together - the .go files do not appear in the file list.

https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el/issues/270 is a bug on go-mode which suggests that it isn't just me seeing this problem.

What is required to change this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like adding

```
(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".go")
```

Might be a big part of the solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate, explaining how/why this helps?

Comment: The function adds the file extension to the `speedbar-supported-extension-expressions` user-option.  The ".go" file extension could also be added directly to the user-option in the customization buffer. The list is used to build `speedbar-file-regexp` which is used inside Speedbar.el to detect the files of interest.  This works when go-mode is installed.

Comment: Ideally the code for the major mode should evaluate the `(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".go")` form to add speedbar support.  When that's not done, the choice is to add the extension support to the customizable user-option or to place this code somewhere, like the Emacs init code.